# Storing a value from one record in another record

Tags: haskell

So in my Java program, I have these two class declarations. I want to give the equivalent data type definitions in Haskell (or as close as I can get)

```
class Person {
String name;
Date   dob;
int    ssn;
}

class Date {
int    month; 
int    day;
int    year;
}
```

Can I do something like this? Just use two record, but one record holds the value for another record? This is what I think I can do below :

```
data Person { name :: String, 
              date_of_birth :: Date,
              ssn :: Int
            } deriving (Show)

data Date { month :: Int,
             day :: Int,
             year :: Int
           } deriving (Show)
```

Could something like this work? If not, what would be your suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: Are you just asking if one record can hold an instance of another record. Yes, there's no reason you can't. Did you try using this code?

Comment: In Haskell all (mono)types are first-class: a record field can be of any type, including functions, pairs, lists, or records (including the record type we are defining right now). Ditto for function arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it will work perfectly, however you have to write it like this

```
data Person = Person { name :: String, 
                       date_of_birth :: Date,
                       ssn :: Int
                     } deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

data Date = Date { month :: Int,
                   day :: Int,
                   year :: Int
                 } deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
```

There was a syntax error in your code, I fixed it. I also added `Eq` so you can test if two persons are equal. I added `Ord` so you can put them in data-structures which require the content to be ordable.